# Menu selection not working in Bokeh multiple dashboard generator

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a script that prompts the user, using easgui, for the names of their systems of interest and parameters of interests and several other configs. Then proceeds to create Bokeh (using version '2.4.3') dashboards for all of the parameters and systems where there is one dashboard for each system containing all of the available required parameter data for that dashboard. At the end of my script, I have defined a menu so that the user may select which system's dashboard they see once the entire thing is generated. But the menu doesn't work in the sense that it only displays the default and selecting any options from it doesn't change what is actually being displayed.

Below is the minimal reproducible example:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from bokeh import plotting
from bokeh import layouts
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets.markups import Div
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, TapTool, Button, ColumnDataSource, Select, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.io import curdoc

systems=['TestSys1', 'TestSys2']
dashboards={}
dash_sources={}
index_list = list(range(len(systems)))
sys_figs={}
for idx in index_list:
    system=systems[idx]
    save_loc=r'.\Test'
    customer='TestCustomer'
    all_or_view='all'
    conceal_params=False

    sys_figs[system] = {}

    system_params=['p_1', 'p_2', 'p_3', 'p_4']

    first_logtime = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    last_logtime = '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    
    # Initialise objects for tracking things that need to be tracked
    indices = list(range(len(system_params)))
    shared_x_range = None
    figures = {}
    sources = {param:ColumnDataSource() for param in system_params}
    
    for idx in indices:
        param_name = system_params[idx]
        param_id = system_params[idx]
                
        param_name_normalised = param_name.replace(' ', '')

        raw_label=param_name

        dates = pd.date_range(start=first_logtime, end=last_logtime, freq='D')
        data = np.random.randn(len(dates), 1)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=dates, columns=[param_name])
        df.index.name='LogTime'
        src=ColumnDataSource(df)
        

        prepared_param_data={'source':src}

        # Save the param_last_log_time for this param so that the update function can then query
        # the database and stream and plot only data that has LogTime greater than the previous 
        # param_last_log_time, if any.

        sources[param_name].data = dict(prepared_param_data['source'].data)

        ## Set shared_x_range ##
        if len(figures) > 0:
            first_plotted_param = list(figures.keys())[0]
            shared_x_range=figures[first_plotted_param].x_range
        else:
            shared_x_range=None

        ## Instantiate figures ##
        
        if shared_x_range != None:
            sys_figs[system][param_name] = plotting.figure(x_axis_label='DateTime',
                                y_axis_label=raw_label,
                                x_range=shared_x_range,
                                x_axis_type='datetime',
                                title=raw_label,
                                toolbar_location='right')
        else:
            sys_figs[system][param_name] = plotting.figure(x_axis_label='DateTime',
                                y_axis_label=raw_label,
                                x_axis_type='datetime',
                                title=raw_label,
                                toolbar_location='right')
        
        ## Plot line glyph for data ##
        sys_figs[system][param_name].line(x='LogTime', 
                                            y=raw_label, 
                                            source=src, 
                                            color='#47ed00',
                                            line_alpha=0.7,
                                            muted_alpha=0.2,
                                            legend_label=raw_label)
        
        
        param_fig = sys_figs[system][param_name]
        
        if param_fig != None:
            figures[param_name_normalised] = param_fig

    # Construct dashboard
    figure_columns=[layouts.column(figures['p_1'], figures['p_2']),
                    layouts.column(figures['p_3'], figures['p_4'])]

    dashboard = layouts.row(figure_columns)
    
    dashboard_title = Div(text=f"{system} Dashboard", style={'font-size':'30px', 'color':'black'}, width=3000)

    dashboard = layouts.column(dashboard_title, dashboard)
    
    dashboards[system]=dashboard
    dash_sources[system]=sources
    print(f'Dashboard for {system} created.')


# Create a dropdown menu with options for each dashboard key
dashboard_keys = list(dashboards.keys())
dashboard_select = Select(title="Select Dashboard", value=dashboard_keys[0], options=dashboard_keys)

# Create a ColumnDataSource to hold the selected dashboard
selected_dashboard = ColumnDataSource(data={'dashboard': [dashboards[dashboard_keys[0]]]})

def update_dashboard(attrname, old, new):
    selected_dashboard.data = {'dashboard': [dashboards[new]]}
    selected_dashboard.change.emit()

dashboard_select.on_change('value', update_dashboard)

# Create a layout with the dropdown menu and the selected dashboard
layout = layouts.column(dashboard_select, selected_dashboard.data['dashboard'][0])

# Add a callback to update the layout when the selected_dashboard changes
def update_layout(attrname, old, new):
    layout.children[1] = selected_dashboard.data['dashboard'][0]

selected_dashboard.on_change('data', update_layout)

# Add the layout to the current document
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I then serve this by running `bokeh serve --show "C:\Users\a00555655\OneDrive - ONEVIRTUALOFFICE\Documents\Test\StackExchangeExample.py" --port 1535` from the Anaconda command line.

Why is the drop-down menu not working?

I have tried a bunch of stuff but nothing has panned out. The problem appears to be with the callback but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: There is no possible way to speculate without more information: all relevant version information (it is *always* advised to specify relevant versions on every quesstion) and most importantly, a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. that can actually be taken, and run directly, to investigate)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have now provided a minimal reproducible example. @bigreddot

Comment: @Sazed I get `NameError: name 'key' is not defined` when I try to run, please update the code to make sure it is complete / runnable. Additionally, please make sure the code is *minimal*. Any extra styling, tools, unrelated glyphs, etc. anything unrelated to and unnecessary to reproduce the problem should be completely stripped out. It's just distraction that makes it harder for others to help investigate.

Comment: @bigreddot Thank you for taking a look. The only mention of a `key` in the code was in a list comprehension that I have now removed. I have also trimmed the code and removed anything that isn't essential for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

This is is the problem:

```
    selected_dashboard.change.emit()
```

The JS and Python consoles both report the error (are you not seeing these?):

> AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'change' to ColumnDataSource, possible attributes are data, js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, name, selected, selection_policy, subscribed_events, syncable or tags

The example code works for me if I delete that line.

FYI, if you assign an entire new value to `source.data`, e.g. `source.data = new_data`, it is detected automatically—no other action is necessary to trigger an update. Calls to `emit` are only necessary when columns are updated "in place" (and this is discouraged).

Comment: The problem was never that the code didn't run. It's that the Select menu doesn't actually change what is displayed. Even once I remove the `change.emit()`, selecting `SysTest2` from the Select on the dashboard doesn't change anything.

Comment: The code is clearly running (and the plot updating) for me, with both Bokeh 2.4.3 and latest Bokeh 3.1.0